# How does Reaper interpret timecode?

Tags: reaper, timecode, edl, offsets

I'm trying to export audio out of Reaper but the timecode I see inside vs outside of the application are different. I have a tool that can align audio to video automatically using timecode but the audio that is exported from Reaper always starts about halfway through the video. If I import both into Reaper it looks like they should align.

```
According to Reaper
Start offset    Position        EDL file
10:32:48.594 = 10:32:10.19 = 37968594.516667 milliseconds
11:35:29.355 = 11:34:47:20 = 41729355.641667 milliseconds
11:38:06.178 = 11:37:24:10 = 41886178.725000 milliseconds
15:44:38.758 = 15:43:42:04 = 56678758.045833 milliseconds
16:04:58.973 = 16:04:01:03 = 57898973.170833 milliseconds
```

[image: Reaper]

I've also loaded my files into Adobe Premiere to give a visualization of what's going on. If I use the Position time from inside Reaper the audio lines up perfectly. But if I export the EDL from Reaper and convert the milliseconds(Start time) to timecode it starts about halfway through the video. The same thing happens if I just read the data from the audio file to generate a start time.

[image: Premiere]

Why is it that inside of Reaper everything aligns but outside of Reaper all of sudden everything is offset? Why does Reaper think 15:43:42:04 = 56678758.045833 milliseconds?